# javaFX select mutlipe rows form tableview, put in HashMap

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have a tableview which allows the user to make a single selection. I want to allow the user to make multiple selections from the tableview which will be set as keys in a hashMap, how would i alter the current code to allow this. Any help appreciated.

```
@FXML
TableView<Run> BookingRunTable;

@FXML
TableColumn<Run, String> BookingRunName;

@FXML
TableColumn<Run, Character> BookingRunSize;

@FXML
TableColumn<Run, Double> BookingRunPrice;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    availableRuns = FXCollections.observableArrayList(availableRunList());

    BookingRunName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Run, String>("RunName"));
    BookingRunSize.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Run, Character>("RunType"));
    BookingRunPrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Run, Double>("pricePerNight"));

    BookingRunTable.setItems(availableRuns);
    BookingRunTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
            .addListener(new ChangeListener<Run>() {
                // sets the selected properties of run to detail containers
                @Override
                public void changed(
                        ObservableValue<? extends Run> observable,
                        Run oldValue, Run newValue) {
                    checkRequiredInfo();
                }
            });

    // Then i want the selected rows of the tableview to be put into a Map as the key, so later i can assign other values to the key. 
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> bookingDogRunMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    bookingDogRunMap.put(BookingRunTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getRunID(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Please use standard [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) in the code you post (e.g. `BookingRunTable` should be `bookingRunTable`, etc). It makes it easier to read, and allows the formatter to properly format your code.

Answer (score 0):

To allow multiple selection, in the `initialize()` method call

```
bookingRunTable.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
```

To process all selected rows, use the [`getSelectedItems()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/MultipleSelectionModel.html#getSelectedItems--) method (note the plural) of the `selectionModel`. For example:

```
for (Run run : bookingRunTable.getSelectionMode().getSelectedItems()) {
    bookingDogRunMap.put(run.getRunID(), 0);
}
```